# Use Ansible to copy files to Windows NFS

Tags: windows, ansible

**Overview:**

I have an Ansible node that has a number of files on it. I would like to copy those files over to a remote Network File Share (NFS). I'm trying to limit the number of Windows computers we WinRM into, and so would prefer (if possible) not to need to WinRM to a Windows machine in order to copy the file. Ideally, I would like to be able to copy the file directly from the RHEL Ansible node to the Windows NFS. I say "Windows NFS" but really it is a NAS protected using Active Directory authentication.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to use Ansible to copy from a Linux machine to an NFS (i.e. Windows, Nas, etc.)?
2. Does it matter that the NFS is protected with Active Directory? Must I use some other credentials, or can I use an AD-based username/password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to tackle this would be to mount the Windows Share to the Ansible node. For our use case, a permanent mount would be best. But, you could also use Ansible to temporarily mount the share.

More details can be found here...
[How do you provide domain credentials to ansible's mount module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899186/how-do-you-provide-domain-credentials-to-ansibles-mount-module)